# Mutex not unblocking when unlocked on separate thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am trying to understand why the behavior of my mutex is not as I would expect.

I was debugging another problem, and decided to make a very simple executable to directly test the mutex behavior. This is what I came up with:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        std::mutex myMutex;

        auto threadGenerator = [&] (std::string printout)
        {
                auto threadFunctor = [&, printout] {

                        int count = 0;
                        while (count < 300)
                        {
                                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);


                                std::cout << printout << std::endl;
                                count++;

                                // Sleep ensures that the other thread will be waiting on mutex
                                // when I release lock
                                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
                        }
                };

                return threadFunctor;
        };

        auto thread1Functor = threadGenerator("Thread 1 got lock");
        auto thread2Functor = threadGenerator("Thread 2 got lock");

        std::thread thread1(thread1Functor);
        std::thread thread2(thread2Functor);

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        return 0;
}
```

This just spawns two threads that repeatedly lock and unlock a mutex, while printing some output. I added the sleep to force the lock_guard to block and the threads to wait on each other.

This produces the following output:

```
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
Thread 1 got lock
```

Eventually, once thread 1 is done Thread 2 will start obtaining the lock again.

Shouldn't they be alternating between Thread 1 and Thread 2? The lock should be released at the end of each loop iteration, which should allow the other thread to take control of the mutex. Why isn't that happening? Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: Yeah, that will fix it, but is it necessary to do that? Whenever you use mutexes, is it necessary to add sleep cycles for them to work?

Comment: @user2445507 no it is not necessary

Comment: `std::mutex` does not guarantee fairness.

Comment: Obviously this is toy code to test a concept, but if you want thread A then B and back to A etc... and they never run concurrently you probably don't want a thread at all. You want a state machine.

Comment: I think I would need a condition variable to really get this working as intended. But this was a contrived example anyways. Now I know mutex doesn't guarantee fairness so I will plan for that.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't they be alternating between Thread 1 and Thread 2?

No there is no such guarantee.

> The lock should be released at the end of each loop iteration, which should allow the other thread to take control of the mutex. Why isn't that happening?

Because your first thread locks mutex, sleeps, unlocks mutex and then tries to lock mutex again. Now thread 1 and thread 2 are both trying to acquire mutex, but thread 1 is in running state, while thread 2 is sleeping, so it is much more likely that thread 1 will acquire mutex first.

> Is there any way to make it happen?

You program should not differentiate threads and should not depend on the order. In real situation multiple threads wait for mutex to get data and one thread put it there, so all waiting threads in wait state so there is similar probability they get mutex. But that could be specific for particular hardware, OS and version. You program should not depend on which particular thread acquired mutex.

Answer (score 2):

Put the code when locking the mutex in a separate scope:

```
while (count < 300) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);

        std::cout << printout << std::endl;
        count++;
    } // lock is released here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That only fixes the problem if I keep the sleep in the "// ..." which I would prefer not to do because I'd have many sleeps in the code.

Comment: I don't want the sleep because it will slow down my program. At least, I want to know what is the smallest sleep I could add to guarantee it will work.

Comment: @user Check if [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) after releasing the lock works for your case.

Comment: That does seem to improve things. I still get long chains of print outs from the same thread. Instead of all 300 being together it's chains of 30-40. I would still prefer no chains at all, though

Comment: @user2445507 you are barking on the wrong tree. Your simulation is incorrect, so you do not need make it work, you need to create proper simulation.

Answer (score 0):

As @πάνταῥεῖ says, every time the thread is enter in While loop, the scope is delimited by While's section. So, the `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` is destroyed every when the code into the while has finished and, so on, a new scope is created every time that the thread execute again the while section.

According with CppReference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard:

> When control leaves the scope in which the lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the mutex is released.
>   The lock_guard class is non-copyable.

That is the reason that you have a behaivor like this:

[image]

If you want to lock all the threadFunctor you should take out the lock_guard out of the while, like this:

```
std::mutex myMutex;

auto threadGenerator = [&](std::string printout)
{
    auto threadFunctor = [&, printout] {
        //Scope of threadFunctor
        int count = 0;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex); //The Lock is working into the Scope of threadFunctor

        while (count < 100)
        {
            //New Scope is create (While's Scope)
            std::cout << printout << std::endl;
            count++;
            // Sleep ensures that the other thread will be waiting on mutex
            // when I release lock
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }

        //At this point the Lock will be released.
    };

    return threadFunctor;
};
```